# Сложный SQL-запрос к БД

Tags: mysql, sql

существует база данных travel, в ней есть 2 таблицы: entries и fields

[image: db travel]

Таблица entries (PRIMARY KEY: entry_id):

[image: table entries]

Таблица fields (PRIMARY KEY: id, FOREIGN KEY: entry_id ):

[image: table fields]

Я делаю следующий запрос к БД:

```
SELECT e.entry_id, f.id, e.starred, f.value
FROM entries e INNER JOIN fields f
ON e.entry_id = f.entry_id 
WHERE value = '0'
```

Получаю:

[image: result 1]

Вообще, в этот запрос value динамически подставляется в sql-выражение, но я привел упрощенный вариант. В данном случае в value может придти или '0' или '1'. В боевом проекте туда будут приходить разные значения, не только 0 и 1.

Теперь подставлю в value значение '1': `WHERE value = '1'`, получаю:

[image: result 2]

Но мне нужно несколько иное поведение, а именно: если в таблице fields существует больше одной записи c одинаковым значением entry_id, то в выборку включить field только в том случае, если у него наибольший id (из тех field-ов c одинаковым значением entry_id). В данном случае entry_id=1, наибольший id равен 2, значит field c id=1 в выборку не идет, тк в таблице fields существует field с таким же entry_id=1 и id=2:

[image: exclude]

В выборке также остаются записи (field-ы), если их внешний ключ entry_id уникален, т.е. не существует больше field-а c таким же entry_id.

[image: result 3]

Comment: значит приджойнить надо не таблицу, а подзапрос который делает вашу логику.

Comment: Версия MySQL какая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В последней версии MySQL 8 можно использовать оконные функции:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 
      e.entry_id, f.id, e.starred, f.value,
      row_number() over (partition by e.entry_id order by id DESC) rn
  FROM entries e 
  INNER JOIN fields f USING(entry_id) 
) SELECT
    entry_id, id, starred, value
FROM data
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

[MySQL window function test online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=42e2d852e180863fa2f590fba34ca12f&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

MySQL 5.7 используем подзапрос

```
SELECT 
  e.entry_id, 
  f.id, 
  e.starred, 
  f.value
FROM entries e 
INNER JOIN fields f USING(entry_id) 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT entry_id, MAX(id) max_id
    FROM fields 
    GROUP BY entry_id
) max_fields ON max_id = f.id
```

[MySQL 5.7 sub-query online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1e1af7c799752e95d52a748985f62643&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)